# Javascript on html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner of javascript after learning HTML and CSS, my examples are not given me my expected result. For example, this following code is not giving me the response feedback.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Script</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var perfectNumber = 12;

    function checkApples(numApples) {
      if (numApples == perfectNumber) {
        alert("You ate the perfect number of apples!");
      } else if (numApples > perfectNumber) {
        alert("You ate way too many apples.");
      } else if (numApples < perfectNumber) {
        alert("You didn't eat enough apples.");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <form method="POST" name="applesForm" onSubmit="checkApples(document.applesForm.numApples);">
      <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numApples" />
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

I will highly appreciate a helpful answer.

Comment: **Typo:** Your `form` started with `<formmethod=` which I corrected to `<form method=`.

Comment: If you found an answer that helped you dont forget to mark it as the answer for the future viewers

Answer (score 2):

Inside your function you were using the DOM element instead of the value

```js
var perfectNumber = 12;
function checkApples(numApples)    
{
    console.log(numApples);
    var value = numApples.value; //get the value
    if (value == perfectNumber)    
    {
        alert("You ate the perfect number of apples!");
    }
    else if (value > perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You ate way too many apples.");
    }
    else if (value < perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You didn't eat enough apples.");
    }
}
```

```html
<html>   
<head>  

<title>My Script</title>  

<body>
<form method="POST" name="applesForm"  onSubmit="checkApples(document.applesForm.numApples);">    
 <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numApples" />    
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" />    
</form>


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.applesForm.numApples.value
```

instead of

```
document.applesForm.numApples
```

`numApples` just gives you the DOM element

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use this code:

```html
<html>   
<head>  

<title>My Script</title>  
<script type="text/javascript">
var perfectNumber = 12;
function checkApples(numApples)    
{
    if (numApples == perfectNumber)    
    {
        alert("You ate the perfect number of apples!");
    }
    else if (numApples > perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You ate way too many apples.");
    }
    else if (numApples < perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You didn't eat enough apples.");
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<!-- You need the value of the input not the HTML -->
<form name="applesForm"       onSubmit="checkApples(document.applesForm.numApples.value);">    
 <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numApples" />    
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" />    
</form>


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add some explanations

Comment: because this line i in the onSubmit it says `document.applesForm.numApples.value`

Comment: In fact, this code works accurately. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var perfectNumber = 12;
function checkApples()    
{
   
var numApples=document.getElementById("numApples").value;
    if (numApples == perfectNumber)    
    {
        alert("You ate the perfect number of apples!");
    }
    else if (numApples > perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You ate way too many apples.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You didn't eat enough apples.");
    }

}
```

```html
<form method="get" name="applesForm">    
 <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numApples" />    
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" onclick="checkApples()" />    
</form>
```

Don't worry! You are doing great.

It's just a beginning and there's way more to learn and also feel free to ask any question or query on this social platform.

Anyway, here is the working code. I made only a few changes into the code and I hope that you will easily understand them. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Hello though there are already many answer I just added a different way hopeit helps you .I just used value  to get Input Text value Property

```js
var perfectNumber = 12;
function checkApples()    
{

var n = document.getElementById("numApples").value;
    if (n == perfectNumber)    
    {
        alert("You ate the perfect number of apples!");
    }
    else if (n > perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You ate way too many apples.");
    }
    else if (n < perfectNumber)
    {
        alert("You didn't eat enough apples.");
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="applesForm"    onSubmit="return checkApples()">    
 <input type="text" name="numApples" id="numApples" />    
 <input type="Submit" name="Submit" />    
</form>
```